# Array of formGroup within mat-table for each row

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have an array of formGroup, where each element represents a form. Next I have a mat table, where what I want to do is to generate each tr (so each row) as a distinct form, so that the i-th row of the table is linked to the i-th formGroup. So inside the i-th row, each td element contains an input, and this input should be linked to a formControl which is inside the i-th formGroup.

So basically each row is a form, which can be submitted individually (each row also has a "Submit" button).

How can I accomplish this? Can you provide me a boiler plate I can work on?

Edit: here's what I tried so far: https://angular-dpwgzp.stackblitz.io
where I get "Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive." Also, I have no Idea about where to put the  tag in each row.

Comment: Example added to show what I mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's difficult help if we can't get access to the code.

In [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh?file=app/table-basic-example.html) I put a simple example. See that we create a form Array like

```
myformArray = new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl("uno"),
      surname: new FormControl("one")
    }),
    new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl("dos"),
      surname: new FormControl("two")
    }),
    new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl("tres"),
      surname: new FormControl("three")

    })])
```

The dataSource of the table is the formArray controls.

```
  dataSource = this.myformArray.controls;
```

In this way, "element" is a FormGroup, so a cell can be like

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
       <input [formControl]="element.get('name')">
       </td>
  </ng-container>
```

See that we use [formControl]. That's. A mat-table iterate over myformArray.controls, that is only an array of FormGroups. The FormGroup is this "element", so element.get('...') is a FormControl. It's the reason we can use [formControl]=element.get('...')

it's like we write not mat-table

```
<div *ngFor="let element of myformArray.controls">
  <input [formControl]="element.get('name')">
  <input [formControl]="element.get('surname')">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry I forgot to make the Stackblitz public. Two questions:
1) I cannot make it work if dataSource is an observable
2) Where would you put the <form> tag in each row so that each row can be individually validated/submitted?

Comment: To clarify question 1), suppose I get in your example the data name/surname from a db (the type is "[{name:string, surname:string}]"). I pipe this array into a FormArray, replacing each "{name:string, surname:string}" with a new FormGroup({name: new FormControl(name), surname: new FormControl(surname)}), and this becomes the async dataSource. The page is displayed, however if I change an input it does not reflect on the form controls.

Comment: I love FormArray. if you want validate individuals lines you can use element.valid, see stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-agbgpg?file=app/table-basic-example.html. You can see that there is no form tag. Take account that the formArray exist independienty you has a form or nor, use a clasic `<form>` or `[formControl]`.- e.g. if your .html it's empy, the formArray still exists- You choose how show the formArray. Well, in example we make the formArray by code, generally you make a `httpClient.get` and, **inside** susbcribe create the formArray and datasource=formArray.controls