# How can I create a dynamic table with reactive forms in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-table

I have created a dynamic table in Angular with the help of mat-table, and now I want to add reactive form to it, but I don t manage to put it in place. I think I need to use formArrayName.

the HTML component code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-table
      class="xsm-LaborOutputDrawerTable"
      #table
      [dataSource]="items"
      [formArrayName]="actualsVolumeData">
    <ng-container
        *ngFor="let column of columns; let i=index"
        [stickyEnd]="i === columns.length-1 ? true : false"
        [matColumnDef]="column.columnId">
      <mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.label}} </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell
          [ngClass]="{'xsm-LaborOutputDrawerTable-settingCode': !i }"
          [formGroupName]="i"
          *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field  *ngIf="!!i && i < columns.length - 1" appearance="legacy" >
          <!-- [value]="element[column.columnId]" -->
          <input matInput
              class="xsm-LaborOutputDrawerTable-input"
              formControlName ="element.column"
          >
          <mat-icon *ngIf="i === 1" matSuffix>done</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
        <span *ngIf="!i">
          {{element[column.columnId]}}
        </span>
        <button
            mat-button
            *ngIf="i === columns.length-1"
            (click)="onResetRowClick(element)">
          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnFields"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnFields;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</form>
```

in the component code I have this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'xlm-labor-model-output-drawer-table',
  templateUrl: './labor-model-output-drawer-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./labor-model-output-drawer-table.component.scss'],
})
export class LaborModelOutputDrawerTableComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any[] = [];
  columnFields: any[];
  columns = [{ columnId: 'settingName', label: '' }, { columnId: 'applyToWeeks', label: 'Apply to all Weeks' }];
  // columns: any;
  rows: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ actualsVolumeData: this.rows });

  @Input() gridSource: any = [];
  @Input() dataSource: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDisplayedColumns();

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      columns: this.columns,
    });
  }

  getDisplayedColumns(): any {
    this.columns = this.columns.concat(this.dataSource.columnInfo.map((col) => ({ columnId: col.headerName, label: col.headerName })));
    this.columns.push({ columnId: 'actions', label: 'Actions' });
    this.columnFields = [...this.columns.map((x) => x.columnId)];
    this.items = this.gridSource.settings.map((setting) => {
      const row = {};
      this.dataSource.columnInfo.forEach((column, idx) => {
        row['settingName'] = setting.settingDisplayName;
        row['applyToWeeks'] = setting.settingDisplayName;
        row[column.headerName] = setting.weekData[idx].value;
        row['applyToWeeks'] = 0;
      });
      return row;
    });
  }

  onResetRowClick(row): void {
    const keys = Object.keys(row);
    const a = ['applyToWeeks', 'applyToWeeks', 'settingName'];
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      if (!a.includes(key)) {
        row[key] = 0;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

what solution do you guys have for this ? 
I saw some alernative but all of them are messy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566003/array-of-formgroup-within-mat-table-for-each-row/56571113#56571113 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562871/angular-6-html-table-create-dynamic-columns-and-rows/56664523#56664523

Comment: Iam facing the same issue.
I have a table with all fields are editable and user can also add a new empty row by clicking a add new button. and the entire table is wrapped in a form to validate the rows