# access values changes in table with input ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to detect the changes in a table that contains a a column with inputs.
I'm able to set the values through [value]="element.value" but, how can I detect the change in a value inside the ngFor of the table? I'm trying to set a fromBuilder array, but I get the following error:

core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_rawValidators' of null

I have never worked with fromArrays and any help would be great:

Thanks!!

my ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-config',
    templateUrl: './app-config.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-config.component.scss'],
})

 ngOnInit(): void {
       
        this.objectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            formData: this.formBuilder.array([])
        });
```

my html:

```
<form fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" [formGroup]="objectForm">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="this.dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rootKey}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="value" formArrayName="formData">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;  let index = index">
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <input matInput [type]="element.type" [value]="element.value" [formControlName]="element.value"> //this doens't work
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>



    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: you can not use in the same tag [value] and [formControlName].

Comment: If you want use a mat-table and a FormArray you should use "[formControl]". generally you use as dataSource the FormArray.controls. It's a bit old,but you has an example in this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566003/array-of-formgroup-within-mat-table-for-each-row/56571113#56571113

Answer (score 0):

on your deleted question : *convert object to its original form [closed]*

```js
const data1 = 
  { 'logApp.logText'          : 'kajsdhas'
  , 'logApp.refresh'          : 5
  , 'logDocker.logText'       : 'Hola Emili!'
  , 'logDocker.refresh'       : 30
  , 'dockerMotor.speed'       : '100'
  , 'dockerMotor.range'       : '64'
  , 'dockerMotor.enabled'     : true
  , 'dockerMotor.plcIP'       : '0000000'
  , 'dockerMotor.port'        : 502
  , 'dockerMotor.waitTime'    : '10'
  , 'dockerMotor.chatEnabled' : true
  } 
const data2 = 
  Object
  .entries(data1)
  .reduce((obj,[keys,val])=>
    {
    let elm = obj
    keys.split('.').forEach((key,i,{[i+1]:next}) =>
      {
      if (next) 
        {
        if (!elm[key]) elm[key] = {}
        elm = elm[key]
        }
      else  elm[key] = val
      })
    return obj
    },{})

console.log( data2 )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how to make it to reward you...

Comment: @novita a simple click on my post (on the ▲) if not, I also have plenty of other good answers, which you should pay your attention to ...