# How to create reactive form for each table row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

As you can see I have a code that pulls the data that is to be rendered on the table , each row has an input field , I want to add reactive form to  input fields on each row.

On the mat cell you see that I looped `<mat-cell *matCellDef="let model" class="p-2">` each model has it own mat-form-field

the model should be each data row as you can see on the table.

#code that calls the data to be populated on the table

```
 private getDetails() {    
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.service
    .getDetails(this.filterModel)
    .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
    .subscribe({
      next: (res) => { 
        this.table.data = res.items as Array<any>;
        this.table.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;   
      },
      error: (err) => {
        
      },
      complete: noop,
    });
  }
```

#creates model form code - the model should be the each row data of the table

```
modelForm: FormGroup;

  this.modelForm = this._createModelForm(this.model);

      private createModelForm(model): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
          id: model.id,
          start: model.dateStart,
          end: model.dateEnd,
        });
      }
```

#html code

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="table.dataSource" [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}" matMultiSort
    (matSortChange)="table.onSortEvent()">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="inspectionId">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-multi-sort-header="id">
            <span class="text-left">COLUMN 1</span>
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let model" class="p-2">
            <form [formGroup]="modelForm">
                <div fxLayout="row" class="inspection-schedule-property-border-bottom" style="width: 99%;">
                    <div fxFlex="40" class="inspection-schedule-property-header-sub-label">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="padding-right: 8px;" fxFlex="40">
                            <mat-label>
                                enter date
                            </mat-label>
                            <mat-date-range-input>
                                <input matStartDate placeholder="start date" required formControlName="start">
                                <input matEndDate placeholder="end date" required formControlName="end">
                            </mat-date-range-input>
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.controls.start.hasError('required')">Start date is
                                required</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.controls.end.hasError('required')">End date is
                                required</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
            </form>

        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: If you don't mind but what is the reason for put every row with the form?

If you need for related to edit functionality then you can do a single form with that functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566003/array-of-formgroup-within-mat-table-for-each-row/56571113#56571113

Comment: purvesh , it should be per row so that when I edit e field , the field on that row that I edited is the only one that should be affected.

Comment: any idea guys ?

Comment: @PurveshSangani do you have example Sir based on my code?

Comment: You can use the FormBuilder service and build a form forEach row

Comment: do you have some exampel Sir ? @Nick based on my code above.

Comment: [formBuilder docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder). Basically you call `formbuilder.group({ /* controls */ })` each time so you can have different form groups

Comment: I already have tried the approach Sir , I cant seem to make it work . maybe you can give an example even a snippet based on my code snippet above

Comment: I don't have exact similar example of your code, but I will share you here few links, I hope you are understand.


1) https://muhimasri.com/blogs/add-and-remove-table-rows-using-angular-material/

2) https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-operations-using-dialog/