# How can I set an automatic focus in the input for a keyCode navigation?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, keycode

I have written a table and in it all  contain input fields. For this template I have developed a keyCode navigation. A navigation up, down, left and right is possible. What do I have to add to my code so that the cursor is focused directly in the  when navigating?

My Code:

```
// Snippet from HTML
...
<tbody formArrayName="rows">
  <tr *ngFor="let rowControl of rows.controls; let rowIndex = index">
   <td [formGroupName]="rowIndex" appArrowKeyNav *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; let columnIndex = index;">
   <div>
        <span>
               <label>
                   <input [formControl]="rowControl.get(column.attribute)">
                </label>
         </span>
     </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
// TS
public move(object: any) {
    const inputToArray = this.inputs.toArray();
    const cols = this.displayedColumns.length;
    let index = inputToArray.findIndex((x) => x.element === object.element);
    // console.log('Index found:', index);
    switch (object.action) {
      case 'UP':
        index -= cols;
        break;
      case 'DOWN':
        index += cols;
        break;
      case 'LEFT':
        index -= 1;
        break;
      case 'RIGHT':
        index += 1;
        break;
    }
    if (index >= 0 && index < this.inputs.length) {
      console.log('Navigating to index:', index);
      inputToArray[index].element.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
```

```
// Directive
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'ArrowUp':
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'UP' });
        break;
      case 'ArrowLeft':
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'LEFT' });
        break;
      case 'ArrowDown':
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'DOWN' });
        break;
      case 'ArrowRight':
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'RIGHT' });
        break;
      case 'Enter':
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'ENTER' });
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is myStackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-zfkyyx?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Where does it fail?

Comment: I have tried to implement, unfortunately does not work. I have implemented my code in Stackblitz. Unfortunately the table doesn't work on my Directive... Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? My work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-zfkyyx?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: What means `does not work` what do you expect. what does fail?`please be as clear as possible. assume we know nothing - because.. we do!

Comment: with does not work I mean that the directive in my table does not react when I click into the input field and then try to navigate with the arrow keys. I have implemented everything and do not know why it does not work.

Comment: Can you maybe take a look at my stackblitz? Maybe you can find the error.

Comment: Remove `arrow-div` from your `<ng-template>` it adds Comment type nodes to your query list which have no `focus()` function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562871/angular-6-html-table-create-dynamic-columns-and-rows/56664523#56664523 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to have a table with cells that can be navigated with Arrow keys

use the `id` attribute to store row and col information using the `*ngFor` index

```
    <tr *ngFor="let rowControl of rows.controls; let i = index">

      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">

        <td>
          <input [id]="'row-' + i + '-col-0'" formControlName="name" (focus)="onFocus($event)">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input [id]="'row-' + i + '-col-1'" formControlName="age" (focus)="onFocus($event)">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input [id]="'row-' + i + '-col-2'" formControlName="color" (focus)="onFocus($event)">
        </td>

      </ng-container>

    </tr>
```

in this case id for first row will be `row-0-col-0`, `row-0-col-1` etc.
2nd row `row-1-col-0`

also there is a `onFocus` event handler which will set the current cell in focus

once `keyUp` is triggered

```
 @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    console.log(event.key);

    if (this.currentInputInFocus) {
      const id = this.currentInputInFocus.id;

      if (id && id.includes('row-')) {
        const arr = id.split('-');
        let row: number = Number(arr[1]);
        let col: number = Number(arr[3]);

        switch (event.key) {
          case 'ArrowUp':
            --row;
            break;

          case 'ArrowLeft':
            --col;
            break;

          case 'ArrowDown':
            ++row;
            break;

          case 'ArrowRight':
            ++col;
            break;

          case 'Enter':
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
        this.setFocus(row, col);
      }
    }
  }
```

get the currently focused element id, eg. 'row-0-col-0' and make changes to row or col values depending on a keypress then try to focus the new element

```
  private setFocus(row: number, col: number) {
    const newElementToFocusOn = document.getElementById(`row-${row}-col-${col}`);
    if (newElementToFocusOn) {
      this.currentInputInFocus = newElementToFocusOn;
      this.currentInputInFocus.focus();
    }
  }
```

in `ngAfterViewInit` initially focused cell can be set with:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const row = 1;
    const col = 0;
    this.setFocus(row, col);
  }
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lfvcyu?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts)

**UPDATE**

to use your Stackblitz as context very few mods to make it work:

- set the proper id attributes `[id]="'row-' + rowIndex + '-col-' + columnIndex"`
- keep track of currently focused input: `currentInputInFocus!: HTMLElement;`
- rest is the same as in original demo

[Forked and updated your Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-2mbzgk?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

**UPDATE 2nd**

> The HTMLElement.focus() method sets focus on the specified element, if
> it can be focused.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

One workaround is to add the `tabindex="0"` attribute according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194/2050306)

Back to demo. As @Aviad P. mentioned the directive on `ng-template` is not going to work. Instead:

```
  <ng-template #otherColumns>
    <div tabindex="0" [id]="'row-' + rowIndex + '-col-' + columnIndex" arrow-div>
      Here is a Number
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-zmomed?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

**UPDATE 3rd**

to continue navigating you can try this on `case 'RIGTH':`

```
++col; // try to move to next column

if (col >= this.columns.length) { // check if moved past last column
  col = 0; // go to column at zero index  (1st column)
  ++row; // go to next row
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-dckuoc?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Comment: Very good. I still have one question... What do I have to change my code, so that I can navigate also in <td> focused which are just no input fields? (Like for example the first column accountNumbers in my example).

Comment: do you have an idea what to add to the code so that you can jump to the next row with the keyCode on the right? I have realized that if you are in the first row and navigate to the last column to the right, it is not possible to jump to the next row. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug (well, at least one), you have attached your `arrow-div` to your `<ng-template>` which causes nodes of type `Comment` to be added to your `inputs` `QueryList` - these nodes have no `focus()` function so your code fails.

This is the problem area:

```html
<ng-template arrow-div #otherColumns>
  Here is a Number
</ng-template>
```

Other than that, your index jumps in the wrong gaps when you press the keyboard arrows, but once you fix the previous bug, it does jump around without error.